# Does JBehave converters support generics?

Tags: java, generics, jbehave

Imagine I have following [jBehave](http://jbehave.org/) stories:

```
When I create servers with properties:
| processor | ram  | os  |
| i5        | 8    | win |
| i3        | 4    | lin |

Then ....
```

and

```
When I create install os with properties:
| type   | version  |
| win    | vista    |
| lin    | centOS   |

Then ....
```

And correspondent step definitions for these stories:

```
@When("I create servers with properties:$servers")
public void createServers(Set<Server> servers) ...
```

and

```
@When("I install os with properties:$osSet")
public void createServers(Set<OS> osSet) ...
```

So I need a converter to convert table input to Set and Set. Is it possible to 
write such converters? The problem is that collections differs only in generic type Server and OS.

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine by implementing  [`boolean   accept(Type type)`](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/javadoc/core/org/jbehave/core/steps/ParameterConverters.NumberConverter.html#accept%28java.lang.reflect.Type%29) using [`Type    getGenericComponentType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/GenericArrayType.html#getGenericComponentType%28%29) defined in `GenericArrayType`